# Python animate contour plot for function generated in for loops

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a three-variable function `myfunc` that is generated inside three `for` loops. I want to draw a contour plot of `y` vs `x` and animate this for different times `t`. However, I've looked at the various `matplotlib` examples on the webpage, and am still unsure of how to do this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import animation

def myfunc(x,y,t):
    w = 0.5*x + y + 4*np.sin(1.8*t)
    return w

xlist = np.linspace(0,10,10)
ylist = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
tlist = np.linspace(0,50,50)

plt.figure()

for t in tlist:
    for x in xlist:
        for y in ylist:
            w = myfunc(x,y,t)
    w_vec = np.array(w)
    w_contour = w_vec.reshape((xlist.size, ylist.size))
    w_plot = plt.contourf(ylist,xlist,w_contour)


plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

**Edit:** I quite like the look of [dynamic_image2.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image2.html) in this tutorial. This seems to get things moving, but the axes are wrong:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()

def f(x,y,t):
    return 0.5*x + np.sin(y) + 4*np.sin(1.8*t)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10).reshape(-1, 1)
tlist = np.linspace(0,50,50)

ims = []

for t in tlist:
    x += np.pi / 15.0
    y += np.pi / 20.0
    im = plt.imshow(f(x,y,t))
    ims.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=20, blit=True,
    repeat_delay=1000)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You want an interactive animation, or to save a movie? In the above, are you ending up with just the last frame, or something else?

Comment: I want to show an interactive animation, and also to save a .mp4 if possible. I think I get the final frame, because I haven't set any instructions for plotting animations.

Comment: Start here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html

Comment: @mdurant Thanks, I've already been messing with these for a while now :)

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with your attempt?